# Problem of structure in a mysql database

Tags: mysql, database, data-structures

I have a problem of structure for my database.

I want to know why MYSQL generate the following error:

`#1005 - Can't create table 'test.panier' (errno: 150)`
The variable's name are not important.. its only the structure

Here is my sql file.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Panier;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Materiel;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Medicament;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Produit;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ListePatient;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Patient;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Specialiste;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TelPers;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Personne;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Telephone;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Adresse;

CREATE TABLE Panier(
idPanier        INT(5) NOT NULL,
idProduit       INT(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`idPanier`,`idProduit`),
FOREIGN KEY(idPanier) REFERENCES Specialiste(idPanier),
FOREIGN KEY(idProduit) REFERENCES Produit(idProduit)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Adresse(
idAdresse   INT(100) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
num         INT(5) NOT NULL,
rue         VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
ville           VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
postal      VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Telephone(
idTel           INT(100) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
typeTel     VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
ind         INT(3) NOT NULL,
quartier        INT(3) NOT NULL,
num         INT(4) NOT NULL
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Personne(
idPersonne      INT(100) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
nom             VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
prenom          VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
idTel               INT(100) NOT NULL,
idAdresse       INT(100) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY(idAdresse) REFERENCES Adresse(idAdresse),
FOREIGN KEY(idTel) REFERENCES Telephone(idTel)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE TelPers(
idPersonne      INT(100) NOT NULL,
idTel               INT(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`idPersonne`,`idTel`),
FOREIGN KEY(idPersonne) REFERENCES Personne(idPersonne),
FOREIGN KEY(idTel) REFERENCES Telephone(idTel)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Specialiste(
login           VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
password    VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
profession  VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
idListeP        INT(5) NOT NULL,
idPanier        INT(5),
idPersonne  INT(100),
FOREIGN KEY(idPersonne) REFERENCES Personne(idPersonne)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Patient(
idPatient    INT(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
sexe            CHAR NOT NULL,
anniv           DATE,
assurance   INT(3) NOT NULL,
idPersonne  INT(100),
FOREIGN KEY(idPersonne) REFERENCES Personne(idPersonne)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Produit(
idProduit       INT(100) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
nom         VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
descr           VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
prix            DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL,
qte         INT(100) NOT NULL
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Medicament(
idMedic         INT(100)NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
marque      VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
typeMed     VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
idProduit       INT(100) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY(idProduit) REFERENCES Produit(idProduit)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Materiel(
idMateriel  INT(100) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
rabais      INT(99) NOT NULL,                                                           /* SI PRODUIT VENANT AVEC PRESCRIPTION  */
idProduit       INT(100) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY(idProduit) REFERENCES Produit(idProduit)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Thanks for the help. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an index for the idPanier column in Specialiste table

The table you are creating "Panier" references two columns 
1. Specialiste(idPanier)
2. Produit(idProduit)

idProduit is indexed since it is a primary key

You will need to add index for the idPanier column as well in Specialiste table

Also since the Panier table references other two tables ... those tables should be created first

The updated script is as follows:

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Panier;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Materiel;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Medicament;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Produit;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ListePatient;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Patient;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Specialiste;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TelPers;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Personne;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Telephone;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Adresse;


CREATE TABLE Adresse(
idAdresse   INT(100) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
num         INT(5) NOT NULL,
rue         VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
ville           VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
postal      VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Telephone(
idTel           INT(100) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
typeTel     VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
ind         INT(3) NOT NULL,
quartier        INT(3) NOT NULL,
num         INT(4) NOT NULL
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Personne(
idPersonne      INT(100) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
nom             VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
prenom          VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
idTel               INT(100) NOT NULL,
idAdresse       INT(100) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY(idAdresse) REFERENCES Adresse(idAdresse),
FOREIGN KEY(idTel) REFERENCES Telephone(idTel)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE TelPers(
idPersonne      INT(100) NOT NULL,
idTel               INT(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`idPersonne`,`idTel`),
FOREIGN KEY(idPersonne) REFERENCES Personne(idPersonne),
FOREIGN KEY(idTel) REFERENCES Telephone(idTel)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Specialiste(
login           VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
password    VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
profession  VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
idListeP        INT(5) NOT NULL,
idPersonne  INT(100),
idPanier        INT(5),
INDEX(idPanier),
FOREIGN KEY(idPersonne) REFERENCES Personne(idPersonne)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE Patient(
idPatient    INT(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
sexe            CHAR NOT NULL,
anniv           DATE,
assurance   INT(3) NOT NULL,
idPersonne  INT(100),
FOREIGN KEY(idPersonne) REFERENCES Personne(idPersonne)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Produit(
idProduit       INT(100) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
nom         VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
descr           VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
prix            DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL,
qte         INT(100) NOT NULL
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Medicament(
idMedic         INT(100)NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
marque      VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
typeMed     VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
idProduit       INT(100) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY(idProduit) REFERENCES Produit(idProduit)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Materiel(
idMateriel  INT(100) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
rabais      INT(99) NOT NULL,                                                           /* SI PRODUIT VENANT AVEC PRESCRIPTION  */
idProduit       INT(100) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY(idProduit) REFERENCES Produit(idProduit)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Panier(
idPanier        INT(5) NOT NULL,
idProduit       INT(100) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY(idPanier) REFERENCES Specialiste(idPanier),
FOREIGN KEY(idProduit) REFERENCES Produit(idProduit),
PRIMARY KEY (`idPanier`,`idProduit`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: look at INDEX(idPanier) line in the Specialiste table

Answer (score 0):

From [the MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html):

> If you re-create a table that was dropped, it must have a definition
>   that conforms to the foreign key constraints referencing it. It must
>   have the right column names and types, and it must have indexes on the
>   referenced keys, as stated earlier. If these are not satisfied, MySQL
>   returns error number 1005 and refers to error 150 in the error
>   message.